# How can i make all the view pages in a controller to refer to a single layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to know if it's possible to let all the view pages in a controller access a single layout page and in which i have multiple controllers with their many view pages such that i need a single specific layout setting corresponding to the specific controller.further if that's not enough to explain i'm adding that we know that there's a viewstart file in the views folder which contains the reference of the layout to be used in all of that controller's views,i want here that a seperate viewstart file be contained in separate controller which point to the layout setting as required if possible then please show me that in answer to the query how to do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you would like a layout for all views in a specific controller rather than the whole project (i.e. using the `_viewStart` in the root of the `Views` folder).

There are a couple of options:

**1.**
Reference the layout in each view. e.g.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

**2.**
Create a `_viewStart.cshtml` in the specific view folder that is associated to the controller.

E.g. if the controller was called `BaconController` there would be a folder under `Views` called `Bacon`. A `_viewStart` file in a folder will always override the default one in the root of `Views`.